# Populating multiple dropdowns with a single mysqli_fetch_array() query to MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I am having trouble populating multiple drop-downs .I need to do it with a single query to db and is it possible to do it within a single while loop?
Here is the code.Only the first dropdown(Player) is getting populated.The database table(playerDB) has 2 columns-Player and Game. and the respective dropdowns need to be populated

```
 <form name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Selecting report</legend>
       <p>
          <?php
             $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydatabase');

             if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
             {
                echo 'Failed to connect';
             }
            else{
              echo '';
            }

            if (!$res=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from playerDB")){
                  echo ("Error description: "  .mysqli_error($connect));
            }
         ?>

         <label>Select Player</label>
         <select>
           <?php
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
             {
           ?>
            <option> <?php echo $row["Player"]; ?> </option           
           <?php
             }
          ?>
        </select>

          <label>Select Game</label>
          <select id = "myGameList">          
             <?php
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
             {
           ?>
            <option> <?php echo $row["Game"]; ?> </option>                
           <?php
             }
           ?>
          </select>
```

Any help would be appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: The reason why only one of your dropdowns is getting populated is because mysqli_fetch_array always moves the result pointer of ($res) forward and it doesn't get reset automatically. Take a look at the code I've answered below. I've added comments accordingly hoping that it helps clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** Instead of using `while()` to populate select-boxes,try to save records in array and then use that array as many time as you want.

***2.*** Also try to fetch only those columns what you actually needed further. It will make query lighter as well as records array lighter too.

Do like below:-

```
<?php
     $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydatabase');

     if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
     {
        echo 'Failed to connect';
     }
    else{
        if (!$res=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Player,Game from playerDB")){ // get that much column only which you want not all
              echo ("Error description: "  .mysqli_error($connect));
        }
    }
    $data = []; //create array 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $data['Player'][] = $row["Player"]; //assign values to array
        $data['Game'][] = $row["Game"];//assign values to array
    }
?>


<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Selecting report</legend>
        <label>Select Player</label>
        <select>
        <?php
            foreach ($data['Player'] as $player){//use array as many times you want 
        ?>
            <option> <?php echo $player; ?> </option           
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <label>Select Game</label>
        <select id = "myGameList">          
        <?php
            foreach ($data['Game'] as $game){//use array as many times you want 
        ?>
            <option> <?php echo $game; ?> </option>                
        <?php
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mysqli_fetch_all` function.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydatabase');

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo 'Failed to connect';
}

if (!$res=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from playerDB")){
    echo ("Error description: "  .mysqli_error($connect));
}

$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($res);
```

Now you can use the `$rows` in your `foreach`

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['Player'];
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['Game'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a single query (which is good). The reason why only one of your drop-downs is getting populated is because `mysqli_fetch_array` always moves the result pointer of ($res) forward and it doesn't get reset automatically. Take a look at the code below. This should solve your problem and also clarify some of your doubts.

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Selecting report</legend>
        <p>
        <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydatabase');

            if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
            {
                echo 'Failed to connect';
            }
            else{
                echo '';
            }

            // Single DB query. This is good. 
            // You could also use "SELECT Player, Game FROM playerDB"
            // This is generally recommended over * because in real-life databases the number of columns in the table can be huge.
            // You should only pick the columns that you need.
            if (!$res=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * from playerDB")){
                echo ("Error description: "  .mysqli_error($connect));
            }

            $player_options = "";
            $game_options = "";

            // Single loop per row. Update the HTML into PHP variables here and then latur re-use these option variables to generate your dropdown(s)
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $player_options .= "<option>".$row["Player"]."</option>";
                $game_options .= "<option>".$row["Game"]."</option>";
            }
         ?>

            <label>Select Player</label>
            <select>
                <?php echo $player_options; ?>
            </select>

            <label>Select Game</label>
            <select id = "myGameList">          
                <?php echo $game_options; ?>
            </select>
```